# Bug with select2 and icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm sort of a newbie and can't figure out why two arrows are showing on the dropdown menu. I want to remove the middle arrow, but if that's not possible I would like to remove all arrows from dropdown menu. I'm on Wordpress installation and using Ionicons with Select2 jquery. I tried with display:none in CSS but that's not working.

[image]

This is what I get when inspect arrow icon on the right (the one arrow in the middle isn't possible to inspect, it's just standing there:

```
<span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
::before
<b role="presentation"></b>
</span>
```

Would really appreciate if you can tell me how to remove those, any solution is welcome.

Comment: Can you please link us to the site, or replicate it in jsfiddle or something alike? It is hard to debug with just an image and some html.

Comment: Hi Phillip can I send you an email because I can't share the site publicly? I will give you the reps afterwards.